# R function inheriting arguments from function that called it

Tags: r, function, lexical-scope

I'm having trouble understanding lexical scoping in R. Take the following functions:

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z) x + f2()
f2 <- function() f3()
f3 <- function() y + z
```

If I call `f1(1, 2, 3)` I expect `f3` to look for `y` and `z` in it's own environment, not find them, then look in the environment for `f2` (which called `f3`), again not find them, then finally look in the environment for `f1`, find them, and return `6`. Instead, `f3` never finds `y` and `z` and returns an error.

I have gathered that this is because functions don't look in the environment of where they were called, but in the environment where they were defined in the first place, so `f3` skips right to the global environment and never searches the other functions' environments. Is that right?

I think I can make it work by passing the arguments along between the functions explicitly, like so:

```
f4 <- function(x, y, z) x + f5(y, z)
f5 <- function(y, z) f6(y, z)
f6 <- function(y, z) y + z
```

but I would rather not because my application has a lot of nested functions that share arguments, and defining them all at every call seems messy and error prone.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Error-prone-ness is in the eye of the code writer.  To me, it is error-prone to define a function with no arguments that operates on objects y and z, whatever those might be at the time of the function call.  And so - to me - the "better" way is to define f3=function(y,z) y+z and call with f3(y,z).  Alternatively, you can define f3() inside of f2() so that any call to f3() searches the scope of f2() rather than the global environment.

Comment: You are right about the lexical scoping of functions.  One resource on this topic is the chapter on functions in Hadley's Advanced R book:  http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Comment: You can't change R from lexical scoping to dynamic scoping. That's a fundamental change to the language. Creating closures rather than separate functions might be an option. It's possible you might just want to consider passing expressions rather than functions. But it's not really clear exactly what your requirements are here. A more realistic example might help and a clear definition of what exactly "better" means in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly define the functions so that they look in the calling environment without having to specifically take named parameters. I can't think of a good use case for this, however, and attempting to do so indicates that you should re-think your design.

Anyway, as a demo, here is how you could rewrite your functions to get the behaviour you describe:

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z) x + f2()
f2 <- function() f3()
f3 <- function() parent.frame(2)$y + parent.frame(2)$z

f1(1,2,3)
#> [1] 6
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it sounds like I need to re-think my design. It's a mess of functions that call each other in various ways, and all use the same arguments. I thought that it would be easier if those arguments could just hang out in the environment of the main parent function and become available to all the other functions, and that that would simplify things.

Comment: @nealmaker sometimes it's difficult to avoid the problem you describe. Usually the best way to do that if you're writing a package is to create a special storage environment as a way of polluting the global namespace, or to take an object-oriented approach so that you can pass single objects around with multiple elements inside

Answer (score 0):

@AllanCameron showed you how to do what you asked, and suggested you re-think your design.  A possible design that makes this easy is to put all of the functions that share args into one big function.  For example,

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z) {
   f2 <- function() {
     f3()
   }
   f3 <- function() {
     y + z
   }
   x + f2()
}
```

Another possibility is to define them all in a common environment.  This is easy to create using `local({ f1 <- ..., f2 <- ..., f3 <- ..., list(f1, f2, f3) })` but it's probably better to think about using some existing object system rather
than defining your own.